# div tag alignment with sidebars extending dynamically

Tags: css, html

I've been playing around with div tags for a while trying to get my basic layout set up. I've worked out how to place all the content Inside the tags but can't seem to figure out my layout. I need my sidebar div to extend the same height as my content div and for everything to be centered. preferably using % for lengths rather than px, so it fits the same on all resolution screens? Refer to picture.
thanks!

Refer to link for image of my layout.

[Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDw0.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle ? Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just needing the content/sidebar part, so here's one of a few possible solutions:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qSZe3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    Content stuff here...

    <div id="sidebar">
        Sidebar stuff here...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px; /* <- change to suit */

    /* v-- just for testing */
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px; /* <- change to suit */

    /* v-- just for testing */
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's start from the begining. As the div is a tag of last resort, you should really use other ways to set up your layout (I recommend using HTML5 with it's new tags to do so like **header**, **nav**, **section** and **aside**).

But, getting to the point, first of all, to keep easily all your elements centered and same width, you should put them all in a wrapper section with similar properties:

```
#wrapper{
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 70%
     min-width: 720px;
     max-width: 1300px;
}
```

Then all your header composites should have set 100% width, and after that divide your content and aside bar by setting them a percentage width like 60%-40% (if that causes aside section to jump down, you should consider making it one percent thiner, and make it right float).

And to keep the main section and the sidebar same height I recommend using Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $hi1 = jQuery('#content').height();
    $hi2 = jQuery('#sidebar').height();

    jQuery('#sidebar').css('min-height', $hi1);
    jQuery('#content').css('min-height', $hi2);
});
```

Thisd way your elements will have dynamically set minimum height depending on the height of the taller element. This way you don't have to set them manually.
Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7TjfF/2/

Comment: Thanking you so very much!

Comment: Tested. doesn't seem to work. I  heard something about installing JQuery. is this correct?

Comment: You have to add the following code to your **head** to use jQuery library:`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`